# Why is $e^\frac{x}{2}$ derived as composed function?

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is $y=e^\frac{x}{2}$ derived as composed function? I mean why $y'=(e^\frac{x}{2})'(\frac{x}{2})' = \frac{1}{2}e^\frac{x}{2}$? I thought that $(e^x)'=e^x$.

What I'm missing? Thank you.

Comment: It's differentiated as a composed function because it _is_ a composed function. It is $e^{f(x)}$ where $f(x) = x/2$. Did you want the derivative of $e^{x/2}$ to be $e^{x/2}$? You can see that that isn't right, because it doesn't have slope $1$ at $x = 0$, it has slope $1/2$.

Comment: Write $y=e^{u(x)}$. So, $y'=e^{u(x)}\times u'(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It IS a composed function. It is $(f \circ g) (x)$ where $f=e^x$ and $g=\frac{x}{2}$.

Also, as a side note. The verb for of derivative is "differentiate" not "derive". You differentiate a function to find its derivative. You take some formulas, theorems, etc. and derive another.